# Выводит ошибку Активити has leaked ServiceConnection

Tags: java, android

```
Activity Активити has leaked ServiceConnection com.anjlab.android.iab.v3.BillingProcessor$1@4220f138 that was originally bound here
                                                                          android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Activity Активити has leaked ServiceConnection com.anjlab.android.iab.v3.BillingProcessor$1@4220f138 that was originally bound here
```

Подозреваю ошибка появляется при закрытии активити, но не пойму почему она получается, сверху лог. Помогите, ибо гугление не помогло(

Comment: вы биндитесь к сервису в активити, но не делаете unbind, и соединение остается.

Comment: Активити уничтожается, а подключенный к ней сервис "повисает" имея соединение, но не имея к чему соединятся. Перед закрытием активити нужно "отвязать" сервис.